# MSBUILD - Referencing a property with @ vs $?

Tags: .net, msbuild

In microsoft's target files that get installed with .net, I've noticed some properties are referenced using both an @ and a $ in different locations? I've done some google searching, and I can't find anything describing the difference between these two usages of the same variable:

```
<SomeProperty>@(_AnotherProperty)</SomeProperty>
<SomeOtherProperty>$(_AnotherProperty)</SomeOtherProperty>
```

What's the difference between referencing _AnotherProperty with a @ versus a $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So i think the answer is, they aren't both properties.  Even though in the target files microsoft uses the same name.

The difference is $(Something) references a property.

> Properties are name-value pairs that can be used to configure builds.
>   Properties are useful for passing values to tasks, evaluating
>   conditions, and storing values that will be referenced throughout the
>   project file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx

@(Something) references a "item."

> MSBuild items are inputs into the build system, and they typically
>   represent files. Items are grouped into item types based on their
>   element names. Item types are named lists of items that can be used as
>   parameters for tasks. The tasks use the item values to perform the
>   steps of the build process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx

What was confusing me in the microsoft targets was the difference between a "Framework Directory" property, and a "Framework Directory Item".  So I'll go on to learn further.  I'm not going to make this as the answer just yet, in case others have a better response.